# LineChart MarkerView disappears ,when dragged on graph and appears back, when I release the drag

Tags: android, kotlin, gesture, mpandroidchart, linechart

MarkerView of LineChart (MpAndroidChart Library) disappears,when I start dragging on the graph and once I release the dragging, it again appears.

I have a requirement to keep the highlight entry(vertical highlight line with Marker) at fixed position on graph.
When we move/drag Graph, graph line should only move.
Higlightline and marker should be at same place always with updated position.

Checked in multiple forums but could not find any solution yet.

Following is the code for reference,

CustomMarkerView Class :

```
class CustomMarkerView(context: Context, layoutResourceId: Int) : MarkerView(context, layoutResourceId) {

private var xPOS = 0f

override fun getOffset(): MPPointF {
    return MPPointF.getInstance(-(width/2).toFloat(), - (height / 2).toFloat())
}

override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, posX: Float, posY: Float) {
    if(xPOS == 0f ){
        xPOS = posX
    }
    super.draw(canvas, xPOS, posY)
}}
```

And Below code inside fragment -

// To setup data to line chart

```
lineChart.run {
        data = uiModel.lineData
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        setVisibleXRangeMaximum(xAxisIntervals.toFloat())
    }
```

// To move the line chart and set highlight entry

```
lineChart.run {
   moveViewToX(xPos)
   highlightValue(HighlightEntry.x, dataSetIndex = 1)
}
```

where xPos is nothing but (Highlighted.x - fixedXIntervals)

Also,Implemented OnChartGestureListener() and used onChartTranslate() to send the Index to fragment

```
override fun onChartTranslate(me: MotionEvent?, dX: Float, dY: Float) {
  graphListener.notifyOnGraphScrolled(lineChart.lowestVisibleX.toInt())
}
```

Any idea how to move the markerView smoother without getting disappeared?

I appreciate any quick help. Thanks.